# How can stream from php media source link on videojs or JWPlayer or Plyr Player?

Tags: php, jwplayer

I am new to html player and I have no idea how I can play media from php/api link source media.

I am using JWPlayer.

Example Media Link : `https://doamin.xyz/xxx/api.php?c=xxxxxxxxxx`

this link play perfectly with VLC and EXO Player.
any one can help me how can i set this media source on JWPlayer ?

```
<script src="//jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="///libraries/IDzF9Zmk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer.key = '';
</script>
</head>
<style>
    * {margin:0}
    .video {widht:100px;hight:50px;margin:0px ;}
</style>

<div id="my-video"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const player = jwplayer('my-video').setup({
        autostart: false,
        mute: false,    
        "default": false,
        type: "hls",
        file: 'https://doamin.xyz/xxx/api.php?c=xxxxxxxxxx',   
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        primary: "html5",
        hlshtml: true, 
        playbackRateControls: false,

    });
</script>
```

Comment: you must provide the return data form of `https://doamin.xyz/...` or the api must work because i need to know what it returns

Comment: I found this from media playing page GET url=
 https://doamin.xyz/xxx/api.php?c=xxxxxxxxxx and location url=
 https://zee5livemedia.zee5.com/v1/master/5c95b915ce5f89df583d7097ff7e9fdb77a6461e/LinearStream-SSAI-POC/out/v1/ae9617b9d66d4564831443eb2cc15caf/index.m3u8?hdnts=st=1677329766~exp=1677332766~acl=/out/v1/ae9617b9d66d4564831443eb2cc15caf/index.m3u8*~hmac=bfc36f08046e29175a525914c5b41678c10e4c710e5697d78cfb82f196adf4c7

Comment: this url result `Unable to obtain template playlist`

Comment: i looked at the url it returns 1 player jwplayer doesn't handle that one. replace `file: 'https://zee5livemedia.zee5.com/v1/master/5c95b915ce5f89df583d7097ff7e9fdb77a6461e/LinearStream-SSAI-POC/out/v1/9bef4425a4cd4bd7acf3242a3156163358? /out/v1/9bef4425a4cd4bd7acf3242a3156162d/index.m3u8*~hmac=b5545de5685c62d64be35d49bcb8f7c479c541135ab439722355e83835408a80'` and it will work i take this url send from your url player